# What is the model/layout of this unbranded keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I have this very handy wireless keyboard + TouchPad thingy. Unfortunately I am struggling finding several special chars on it, making terminal work very.... Slow. In my raspbian OS preferences, there is a "keyboard and mouse" section, it asks for Model, Layout (language?), and variant.

I have tried a few different but none so far seems to fit and there are like 1000 options to choose from and it takes quite a while to apply the settings, so I would be waiting until the end of the week if I were to go through them one by one...

Can anyone recognize this keyboard layout and know what I should select?

[image]

Comment: it is an older version of the VicTsing® 2.4G Mini Wireless Keyboard With Touchpad Mouse. A few manufacturers make it with the same layout. Yours is unbranded and can be specificaly found here: shorturl.at/gltKO

Comment: That's the one. Do you happen to know which model in Linux would be aligned with this layout? "vicTsing" is not on the list unfortunately 

Comment: Isn't there a label on the other side?

Comment: Layout is generically US ANSI. idk specifically, but that's the overall layout scheme. [positions of `~, no key left of Z, # on shift/3, single row Return key, all clues]

Comment: There are some options: 'generic 101-key PC' ... 102, 104, 105. Would it maybe one of those then set to US English?

Comment: You could always spend the afternoon counting keys… then deciding which keys shouldn't be counted, then comparing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout I wish you luck :)

Comment: @Tetsujin ❤️ thx! 105 key English US seems to be the perfect fit!

Comment: Yay. Glad you got it. I wouldn't have got the count right at three re-counts. Put yourself an answer in & accept it.

Comment: @RasmusPuls how did you find that from that link?

Comment: @RasmusPuls I don't see the mystery then.  The article says "The U.S. IBM PC keyboard has 104 keys, while the PC keyboards for most other countries have 105 keys."    So your keyboard fits the "for most other countries". And even then you picked US. And where did you even see options like "Generic 101-key....105" Are you configuring a Raspberry Pi https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/487498.image0.jpg

Comment: @barlop what article? I chose English US because Tetsujin told me that it looked like a US layout. The "Generic 101-key....." are options in my Linux (raspbian) under: preferences -> mouse & is keyboard -> keyboard -> model. In that list there is ~100 things to chose from. For each selected item model there is a gazillion languages. Since I don't know what model or language this keyboard is.... It's not a mystery it's just a simple question to whoever might know.

Comment: @RasmusPuls You write "For each selected item model there is a gazillion languages" <---  there is a dollar sign above the 4.  There's a very famous enormous country that uses dollars. And you didn't try US? And you wonder what of a "gazillion" languages it could be.

Comment: @RasmusPuls also this screen shows 4 obvious options to try try https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/3274/files/keyboard3_grande.png?13307922366601850111